# AMD/ATI ES1000 VGA Card slows down Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ati, radeon, gpu-driver

I freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit (and after that the 32 bit but did not work). It runs very slow. After checking the forum I narowed down the problem to the graphics card. Does anyone know what to do? Looking for additional drivers returns nothing.
  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ES1000 does not have hardware support for 3D acceleration so it will be very slow with modern compositing desktops like Unity. Try Lubuntu or Xubuntu.